# R conditional grouping of rows and numbering of groups

Tags: r, grouping

I work with data frames for flight movements (~ 1 million rows * 108 variables) and want to group phases during which a certain criterion is met (i.e. the value of a certain variable). In order to identify these groups, I want to number them.
Being a R newbie, I made it work for my case. Now I am looking for a more elegant way. In particular, I would like to overcome with the "useless" gaps in the numbering of the groups.
I provide a simplified example of my dplyr data frame with the value THR for the threshold criterion. The rows are sorted by the timestamp (and thus, i can truncate this here).

```
THR <- c(13,17,19,22,21,19,17,12,12,17,20,20,20,17,17,13, 20,20,17,13)
df  <- as.data.frame(THR)
df  <- tbl_df(df)
```

To flag all rows where the criterion is (not) met

```
df  <- mutate(df, CRIT = THR < 19)
```

With the following, I managed to conditionally "cumsum" to get a unique group identification:

```
df <- mutate(df, GRP = ifelse(CRIT == 1, 0, cumsum(CRIT))
df
    x CRIT GRP
1  13 TRUE   0
2  17 TRUE   0
3  19 FALSE  2          
4  22 FALSE  2
5  21 FALSE  2
6  19 FALSE  2
7  17 TRUE   0
8  12 TRUE   0
9  12 TRUE   0
10 17 TRUE   0
11 20 FALSE  6
12 20 FALSE  6
```

While this does the trick and I can operate on the groups with group_by (e.g. summarise, filter), the numbering is not ideal as can be seen in the example output. In this example the 1st is numbered 2, and the 2nd group is numbered 6 which is in line with the cumsum() result.

I would appreciate, if anybody could shed some light on me. I was not able to find an appropriate solution in other posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
 x = rle(df$CRIT)
 mask = x$values
 x$values[mask] = 0
 x$values[!mask] = cumsum(!x$values[!mask])

 mutate(df, GRP=inverse.rle(x))

#   THR  CRIT GRP
#1   13  TRUE   0
#2   17  TRUE   0
#3   19 FALSE   1
#4   22 FALSE   1
#5   21 FALSE   1
#6   19 FALSE   1
#7   17  TRUE   0
#8   12  TRUE   0
#9   12  TRUE   0
#10  17  TRUE   0
#11  20 FALSE   2
#12  20 FALSE   2
#13  20 FALSE   2
#14  17  TRUE   0
#15  17  TRUE   0
#16  13  TRUE   0
#17  20 FALSE   3
#18  20 FALSE   3
#19  17  TRUE   0
#20  13  TRUE   0
```

Comment: ;) ... thanks for this. It works fine and I was able to learn about a function I did not know yet: rle(). I need to work out exactly what x$values[!mask] = cumsum(!x$values[!mask]) does. But that is more a newbie problem than an issue with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't you can really avoid that preliminary step of creating `CRIT`, though I'd suggest to add `cumsum` when creating it and then just run a simple `cumsum`/`diff` wrap up on it. Also, If you don't need the groups that aren't meeting the criteria, it is better to assign `NA` instead of just some random number such as zero. Here's a possible `data.table` wrap up (also, you don't need the `df <- tbl_df(df)` step at all)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, CRIT := cumsum(THR < 19)]
df[THR >= 19, GRP := cumsum(c(0L, diff(CRIT)) != 0L) + 1L]
#     THR CRIT GRP
#  1:  13    1  NA
#  2:  17    2  NA
#  3:  19    2   1
#  4:  22    2   1
#  5:  21    2   1
#  6:  19    2   1
#  7:  17    3  NA
#  8:  12    4  NA
#  9:  12    5  NA
# 10:  17    6  NA
# 11:  20    6   2
# 12:  20    6   2
# 13:  20    6   2
# 14:  17    7  NA
# 15:  17    8  NA
# 16:  13    9  NA
# 17:  20    9   3
# 18:  20    9   3
# 19:  17   10  NA
# 20:  13   11  NA
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. This also works fine. I will go with Colonel's solution above as I (for the time being) would like to stick to base R and dplyr.
I will keep the data.table package on my to-do list for the xmas vacation.